# Pushwoosh IOS notifications, onOpen invoked without click

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, pushwoosh

I have an IOS native app with `Pushwoosh` notifications.
When I put the app in background mode (Not killed), and then received a push, methon `onMessageOpened` called, even the user didn’t open the push.

My `onMessageOpened` method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, PWMessagingDelegate {

...
...

    func pushwoosh(_ pushwoosh: Pushwoosh!, onMessageOpened message: PWMessage!) {
    
            var url = message.payload["url"] as! String
            
            let myURL = URL(string:url)
            let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
            self.webView.load(myRequest)
        
    }
}
```

This is in my `AppDelegate`:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        Pushwoosh.sharedInstance()?.handlePushReceived(userInfo)
        completionHandler(.noData)
    }
```

In addition I have a difficult with debugging this issue. Because I received push only in production version. Not in debug mode.

EDIT:
After I add a log calls, I can see it called to onMessageOpened just after receiving a push. You can see the low latency between records.

This is my new code:

```
 func pushwoosh(_ pushwoosh: Pushwoosh!, onMessageReceived message: PWMessage!) {
        NSLog("PushWoosh: message recevied!")

    }
    
    func pushwoosh(_ pushwoosh: Pushwoosh!, onMessageOpened message: PWMessage!) {
        NSLog("PushWoosh: message opened!")

            ...
        
    }
```

And this is my logs after a few hours of device was untouched.

[image]